# Javascript variable variables unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, variables

Before you say this is a dupelicate i have read all the other post and they kinda solved my question but now i need to know why the following comes up as an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
Below i include my whole library so you can see what i have coded in hope this would work please help me

```
php2js.$this->();
```

this is my library

```
php2js = window.php2js || {};

php2js = function () {

  var yourVar1;
  var yourVar2;

  publicFunc1 = function(content) {
    document.write(content);
  }

  publicFunc2 = function(handle, first, last) {
      var string = handle.split(first);
      if (1 in string) {
          var output = string[1].split(last);
          return output[0];
      }
      return '';
  }

  publicFunc3 = function(str,begin,end) {
      t = str.split(begin);
      t = t[1].split(end);
      return t[0];
  }

  publicFunc4 = function(delimiter, string, limit) {
    if (arguments.length < 2 ||
        typeof delimiter === 'undefined' ||
        typeof string === 'undefined') {
        return null
      }
      if (delimiter === '' ||
        delimiter === false ||
        delimiter === null) {
        return false
      }
      if (typeof delimiter === 'function' ||
        typeof delimiter === 'object' ||
        typeof string === 'function' ||
        typeof string === 'object') {
        return {
          0: ''
        }
      }
      if (delimiter === true) {
        delimiter = '1'
      }

      delimiter += ''
      string += ''

      var s = string.split(delimiter)

      if (typeof limit === 'undefined') return s

      if (limit === 0) limit = 1

      if (limit > 0) {
        if (limit >= s.length) {
          return s
        }
        return s
          .slice(0, limit - 1)
          .concat([s.slice(limit - 1)
            .join(delimiter)
          ])
      }

      if (-limit >= s.length) {
        return []
      }

      s.splice(s.length + limit)
      return s
  };

  publicFunc5 = function(text, name, type) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = name;
        a.click();
  }

  publicFunc6 = function(id, string) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.innerHTML = string;
  }

  publicFunc7 = function(grab) {
    var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    var $_GET = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var temp = parts[i].split("=");
        $_GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
    }

    return $_GET[grab];
  }

  publicFunc8 = function(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }

  publicFunc9 = function(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  publicFunc10 = function() {
    return navigator.userAgent;
  }

  publicFunc11 = function(str) {
        return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }

  publicFunc12 = function() {
    var obj = {}
    obj.foo = 42;

    var bar = 'foo';
    console.log(obj[bar]);
  }

  return {
    "echo" :  publicFunc1,
    "GetBetween" : publicFunc2,
    "GBS" : publicFunc3,
    "explode" : publicFunc4,
    "fcd" : publicFunc5,
    "echoById" : publicFunc6,
    "$_GET" : publicFunc7,
    "setCookie" : publicFunc8,
    "$_COOKIE" : publicFunc9,
    "$UA" : publicFunc10,
    "htmlentities" : publicFunc11,
    "$this->" : publicFunc12
  }

}();
```

Comment: What is this `php2js.$this->();` surely it's not javascript !

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you’re trying to achieve with this `->` syntax in JavaScript, but if you’ve got an object with a `$this->` property, you access it with `obj["$this->"]`. This is too weird to be useful.

Comment: That is part of my javascript library i can edit my question and include the whole libray but it is 149 lines

Comment: "That is part of my javascript library" --- well, it's still not a valid JS.

Comment: @Xufox i am trying to my it like the php variable varible $this->$a

Comment: @JosephJamesShenton Your reply is even more confusing than the question itself.

Comment: its this library https://github.com/dan-da/php2js

Comment: "php2js is a tool that can automatically translate PHP code into Javascript code." --- what could go wrong...

Comment: @dippas sorry i have made my own library i did not know there was another libary called php2js

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: i just want to know if there is a what around my problem being that is keeps throwing out an error

Comment: It is throwing an error because `php2js.$this->();` does not look like a JS code.

Comment: oh is there any other character that can replace the > because i think that is the character that throws it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an object with some methods stored in it.The keys have values that are not valid in the dot syntax. In order to call it with your code, you would need to use bracket notation. Basic idea:

```js
var php2js = (function() {
  return {
    "$this->": function() {
      console.log("hey");
    }
  };
}());

php2js["$this->"]();
```

Comment: So i code do 

   `return {`
        `"$this->" : function () { console.log{"hey"); }`
    `}`
    `php2js["$this->"]();`

Comment: because i have a whole js library that all its functions run from the return so 

return { "function" : myfunction, "function2" : myfunction1 }

Comment: Did you try the code, in the end the return stuff does not matter... I boiled it down to a bare bones example.

Comment: i tried it but is says Uncaught TypeError: php2js.$this-> is not a function and i used your exact code even the php2js["$this->"]();

Comment: I got it i just put it in the reutrn and it worked thank you so much!